# Parsing values of each and every text separated by delimiter in CSV file

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

Trying to create methods for reading and displaying each and every value in CSV file. Had assigned first row of CSV file as the name of functions, which can be called for accessing each text.
I have also constructed an array of objects and associated each object with the row of a CSV file. 
Input for CSV file is taken as a normal text seperated by delimiters. Suppose -

```
    name,age,city 
    Chris,43,Ohio
    Tony,54,NYC
```

My output is correct and it is fetch to another CSV file through a feed generator class.
    But I am unable to parse this output on command line. Where I can call methods directly on FeedGenerator outside the class like -

```
        FeedGenerator.name
        FeedGenerator.age
        FeedGenerator.city
```

Currently my code feeds data as per accordance with attributes provided in this class -

```
    class StarkFeedGenerator < FeedGenerator
      def columns; %w(name); end
    end
```

```
    require 'csv'

    class FeedGenerator
      attr_accessor :source, :feed, :current_row

      def initialize(source_name, feed_name)
        @source = CSV.read(source_name, headers: true)
        @current_row = Row.new
        @feed = []

        # define method by header of source file
        @source.headers.each do |column|
          @current_row.instance_eval do
            define_singleton_method(column) do
              self.row[column]
            end
          end
        end

        @feed = CSV.open(feed_name, 'wb+')
        @feed << columns
      end

      def columns
         %w(name age city)
      end

      def generate_feed
        @source.each do |row|
          @current_row.row = row
          @feed << columns.map do |c|
            @current_row.send(c)
          end
        end
      end

      def columns; raise 'unimplimented'; end

      class Row
        attr_accessor :row

        # you can define unrecognized column mapping below
        def name; name; end
        def age; age; end
        def city; city; end
      end
    end
    class StarkFeedGenerator < FeedGenerator
      def columns; %w(name); end
    end

    StarkFeedGenerator.new('Input.csv','new_feed.csv').generate_feed
```

Expected Result :

```
    FeedGenerator.name : Chris, tony
    FeedGenerator.age : 43,54
    FeedGenerator.city : Ohio, NYC
```

Comment: It's not exactly clear what you want to achieve. Can you please elaborate more on what's working as expected and what's not?

Comment: '''@feed = CSV.open(feed_name, 'wb+')'''
        '''@feed << columns'''

Comment: Sorry, but this didn't clarify anything for me

Comment: Through above code I am reading CSV data from source and parsing it into new CSV file "new_feed".csv". But instead I want to display my output on terminal rather pushing it on to another CSV file. So basically source is "input.csv" and output is getting written to "new_feed.csv". I want output in similar fashion on terminal.

Comment: Did I understand correctly that you just want to instantiate some object which you can call methods on (column names) and it should return a list of values of this column?
Like `FeedGenerator.name` returns `Chris, tony`, `FeedGenerator.age` returns `43,54`, etc?

Comment: @GProst yes exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is that what you wanted?

```rb
require 'csv'

class Feed
  def initialize(source_name, column_names = [])
    if column_names.empty?
      column_names = CSV.open(source_name, 'r', &:first)
    end
    columns = column_names.reduce({}) { |columns, col_name| columns[col_name] = []; columns }

    define_singleton_method(:columns) { column_names }

    column_names.each do |col_name|
      define_singleton_method(col_name.to_sym) { columns[col_name] }
    end

    CSV.foreach(source_name, headers: true) do |row|
      column_names.each do |col_name|
        columns[col_name] << row[col_name]
      end
    end
  end
end

feed = Feed.new('input.csv')
puts feed.columns # ["name", "age", "city"]
puts feed.name # ["Chris", "Tony"]
puts feed.age # ["43", "54"]
puts feed.city # ["Ohio", "NYC"]

feed2 = Feed.new('input.csv', ['name'])
puts feed2.columns # ["name"]
puts feed2.name # ["Chris", "Tony"]
```

Note, that I just created `Feed` class instead of `FeedGenerator` since I don't see much point in creating a generator when you can achieve what you want with just `initialize` method.

Also note, with that approach all CSV's rows will be stored in memory (not very good if you have very big CSV), if you want to read from the CSV file only when you call `feed.name`, for example, then this is another approach:

```rb
require 'csv'

class Feed
  def initialize(source_name, column_names = [])
    if column_names.empty?
      column_names = CSV.open(source_name, 'r', &:first)
    end

    define_singleton_method(:columns) { column_names }

    column_names.each do |col_name|
      define_singleton_method(col_name.to_sym) do
        columns = []
        CSV.foreach(source_name, headers: true) do |row|
          columns << row[col_name]
        end
        columns
      end
    end
  end
end

feed = Feed.new('input.csv')
```

Comment: Thanks alot @GProst , I'm progressing with meta-programming and thus quite weak in thinking out of box solutions for now. Tons of thanks.